# Remove certain character from string and return into an array

Tags: javascript

I've got a string that has html tag like this:

```
var list = "<ul><li><p>example 1st</p></li><li><p>example 2nd</p></li></ul>"
```

how can I remove every character of  The u, p, li tags

so i can get return result in array like this :

```
['example 1st','example 2nd']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `div` and then find all the text using `innerText` using `querySelectorAll` and `array#map`.

```js
const list = "<ul><li><p>example 1st</p></li><li><p>example 2nd</p></li></ul>";
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = list;
const text = [...div.querySelectorAll('ul li p')].map(element => element.innerText);
console.log(text);
```

Comment: So this only works for ul, li and p? Not really a good answer IMHO.

Comment: I think you meant `array.map` instead of `array#map`.